# bootstrap modal with asp.net mvc html helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement bootstrap ui modal in asp.net mvc. I created a basic modal which contains a login form.
Issue I am facing here is, when I start using html helpers, styles of the modal form is going really bad. I have attached screenshots below. one screenshot with when I don't use HTML helpers and that's when UI is more clean to view, when I add html helpers, style is going way off.

I have tried pretty much everything I can. I am unable to spot the issue. can someone please have a look at it and throw a light on where I am going wrong.

```
        <div>
            @using(Html.BeginForm()){
                <div class="modal-header modal-hd-bg">
                    <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()">×</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
                </div>        

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form novalidate class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>*@
                            @Html.Label("Email:", new { @class="control-label col-sm-3"})
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                               @* <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="luser.email">*@
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @class="form-control", @placeholder="Enter Email", @id="email" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @*<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>*@
                             @Html.Label("Password:", new { @class="control-label col-sm-3"})
                            <div class="col-sm-9">          
                                @*<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="luser.pwd">*@
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.pwd, new { @class="form-control", @placeholder="Enter password", @id="pwd" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">        
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>        

                <div class="modal-footer modal-ft-bg">
                    <label><u>Don't have an account</u>?</label>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="goToRegister()">Register</button>
                </div>


            }
    </div>
```

[This is when I use @using(Html.BeginForm()) and html helpers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcOeW.png)

[This is when I don't use HTML helpers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRVOY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a form outside another form, because the outside form does not take any input. Nothing wrong with the html helpers.

[image: Modal image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="thisModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-hd-bg">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Login</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <form novalidate class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Email:", new { @class="control-label col-sm-3"})
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email, new { @class="form-control", placeholder="Enter Email", id="email" }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Password:", new { @class="control-label col-sm-3"})
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.pwd, new { @class="form-control", placeholder="Enter password", id="pwd" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">        
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> 

            <div class="modal-footer modal-ft-bg">
                <label><u>Don't have an account</u>?</label>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it definitely did work, I appreciate your response. can we achieve the same by having the form helper of asp.net mvc (outer form) and by removing the inner form altogether? it doesn't seem to be working if I do it.

Comment: That worked for me. I have used it as below:
              @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                          @*   Entire form here .. .*@
                    </div>
                }
Thanks again for your input.